# Docusaurus React has already been declared

Tags: docusaurus

I get this error when i try to go to docs.
Im using the content-docs plugin to put parts of my docs into sections, but for some reason it says that react has already been declared in the markdown file. Is there a settings that I missed inside of the config that I am suppose to set for it to work?

```
ERROR in ./docs/global/index.md
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\Projects\ArmorUp-Wiki\docs\global\index.md: Identifier 'React' has already been declared. (36:205)
```

This is my config

```
// @ts-check
// Note: type annotations allow type checking and IDEs autocompletion

const lightCodeTheme = require('prism-react-renderer/themes/github');
const darkCodeTheme = require('prism-react-renderer/themes/dracula');

/** @type {import('@docusaurus/types').Config} */
const config = {
  title: 'ArmorUP Wiki',
  tagline: 'Dinosaurs are cool',
  favicon: 'img/favicon.ico',

  url: 'https://wiki.armorup.ca',
  baseUrl: '/',

  organizationName: 'ArmorUP Network',
  projectName: 'ArmorUP Wiki',

  onBrokenLinks: 'throw',
  onBrokenMarkdownLinks: 'warn',

  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en'],
  },

  presets: [
    [
      'classic',
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
      ({
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      }),
    ],
  ],

  plugins: [
    [
      'content-docs',
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs').Options} */
      {
        id: 'global',
        path: 'docs/global',
        routeBasePath: '/global',
        sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars/global.js'),
      },
    ],
    [
      'content-docs',
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs').Options} */
      {
        id: 'lifesteal',
        path: 'docs/lifesteal',
        routeBasePath: '/lifesteal',
        sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars/lifesteal.js'),
      },
    ],
  ],

  themeConfig:
    /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').ThemeConfig} */
    ({
      // Replace with your project's social card
      image: 'img/docusaurus-social-card.jpg',
      navbar: {
        title: 'ArmorUp',
        logo: {
          alt: 'ArmorUp',
          src: 'img/logo.svg',
        },
        items: [
          {
            to: "global",
            label: "Global",
            position: "left",
          },
          {
            to: "lifesteal",
            label: "Lifesteal",
            position: "left",
          },
        ],
      },
      footer: {
        style: 'dark',
        links: [
          {
            title: 'Wiki',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Global',
                to: 'global',
              },
              {
                label: 'Lifesteal',
                to: 'lifesteal',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            title: 'Community',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Stack Overflow',
                href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusaurus',
              },
              {
                label: 'Discord',
                href: 'https://discordapp.com/invite/docusaurus',
              },
              {
                label: 'Twitter',
                href: 'https://twitter.com/docusaurus',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            title: 'More',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'GitHub',
                href: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
        copyright: `Copyright © ${new Date().getFullYear()} ArmorUp Network`,
      },
      prism: {
        theme: lightCodeTheme,
        darkTheme: darkCodeTheme,
      },
    }),
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: what is inside index.md file?